# Plotting a function with singularities in TikZ/pfgplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Essentially I want to plot a function with singularities like

```
$\frac{1}{(x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+0.5)^2+(y+0.5)^2}$
```

at a higher sampling rate.

I tried to avoid the singularities by capping with some value ($20$):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={55}{45}]
\addplot3[surf, colormap/jet, samples=50, domain=-1:1] {min(1/((x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2)* 1/((x+0.5)^2+(y+0.5)^2),20)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which yields

[image: Plot]

But that really does not stop TikZ/pfgplots from having to evaluate the function near its singularities, so it gets quite slow at compiling.
So here is my question:

Is there a better/faster way to plot functions that contain singularities? Or do i have to precompute the data and give it to TikZ/pfgplots manually?

Comment: I suspect that the speed has nothing to do with the actual value of the function. You can plot a identically zero function at a resolution of 1000 by 1000 and it will take decades.

Comment: Use LuaLaTeX in conjunction with `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.  This will evaluate the function in Lua which is *much* faster.

Comment: I tried LuaLaTeX and it was MUCH faster.  Then I realized that it wasn't doing anything except showing the same old PDF.  BTW, where does [range3frame] come from?

Comment: I dont think that the singularity is a problem. You can check with `1/max(((x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2)*((x+0.5)^2+(y+0.5)^2),.05)` which has no singularity. The problem is that LaTeX is slow and you ask for `samples=50`.

Comment: @Kpym Is a sampling rate of 50 really that hard? LuaLaTeX is a great option, at least LaTeX wont have to compute the plot every single time. Thanks!
The `range3frame` is a leftover from another plot, it doesn't do anything.